# Spark-submit executor memory issue

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

I have a 10 node cluster, 8 DNs(256 GB, 48 cores) and 2 NNs. I have a spark sql job being submitted to the yarn cluster. Below are the parameters which I have used for spark-submit.
--num-executors 8 \
--executor-cores 50 \
--driver-memory 20G \
--executor-memory 60G \
As can be seen above executor-memory is 60GB, but when I check Spark UI is shows 31GB.
[image]

1) Can anyone explain me why it is showing 31GB instead of 60GB.
2) Also help in setting optimal values for parameters mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I think,

Memory allocated gets divided into two parts:
1. Storage (caching dataframes/tables)
2. Processing (the one you can see)

31gb is the memory available for processing.
Play around with spark.memory.fraction property to increase/decrease the memory available for processing.

I would suggest to reduce the executor cores to about 8-10

My configuration :

spark-shell --executor-memory 40g --executor-cores 8 --num-executors 100 --conf spark.memory.fraction=0.2

Comment: --num-executors 100 ? I have only 8 DNs. Will this work fine? I have 730.6 G  of file to be processed. Will 40G executor memory work along with joins and all?